# Algorithm: Counting elements of Polyomino coverings

Tags: algorithms, recreational-mathematics, polyomino

Given a set of [free Polyominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino#Free,_one-sided,_and_fixed_polyominoes) $\mathcal{P}$ (translation, flipping and rotating of pieces is allowed) and a test shape $S$ that is also a valid Polyomino, I am trying to find an algorithm $f(S, \mathcal{P}) : S \times \mathcal{P} \to (\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{N})$ that counts the number of times entries in $\mathcal{P}$ are used to generate every possible covering of $S$.

A simple example will clarify what I mean. Let

$$
\mathcal{P} = \left\{
    a = \begin{pmatrix}⬛\end{pmatrix},
    b = \begin{pmatrix}⬛\\⬛\end{pmatrix},
    c = \begin{pmatrix}⬛&⬛\\⬛&\end{pmatrix},
    d = \begin{pmatrix}⬛\\⬛\\⬛\\⬛\end{pmatrix}
\right\},
$$

where I have labelled the individual Polyominoes for convenience.

For
$S = \begin{pmatrix}
    ⬛&⬛\\
    ⬛&⬛
\end{pmatrix}
$, that is, the square Tetromino, there are four unique ways to cover $S$ using (possibly repeated) elements from $\mathcal{P}$: $\{ (a, a, a, a), (a, a, b), (b, b), (c, a)\}$. In this case, the algorithm $f(S, \mathcal{P})$ would output $\{a: 7, b: 3, c: 1, d: 0\}$. Note that in general, $S$ will not be rectangular, but any arbitrary Polyomino.

I don't care about efficiency, at the moment I'm simply seeking to define a general brute-force solution that will give the correct answer. My current approach is to treat this as a problem of finding collections of sub-graphs that collectively cover the graph of $S$, but ensuring I don't get duplicate coverings due to transformations of the elements of $\mathcal{P}$ seems like a tricky problem.

Does my specific problem have a name? Are there known solutions or bounds on the complexity?

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I've discovered that my problem is called the [Multihedral Polyomino tiling problem](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/polyominoes/polyominoes.html), and after careful definition of the set $\mathcal{P}$ and shape $S$, can be formulated as a binary integer programming problem.

Burkardt, Garvie and Golomb provide a [GPL licensed Matlab library](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/polyominoes/polyomino_multihedral.html) that formulates and solves such problems!

---

Edit: If anyone else is curious, I've put together a [Python package](https://github.com/aaronsnoswell/polyomino-solver) that wraps the Matlab library to make this easier to use :)